# Make Perl find "wanted" function multithreaded

Tags: multithreading, perl

I have the following code:

```
find(\&jpegCompress, @search_paths);

sub jpegCompress()
{
  #do processing
}
```

Currently it steps through each file one by one in series, which is quite slow. Is there anyway to have the jpegCompress function create a thread (if the thread count is < maxThreads) and return to the find function quickly?

Answer (score 2):

The [Parallel::ForkManager](http://search.cpan.org/~dlux/Parallel-ForkManager-0.7.5/ForkManager.pm) module provides simple parallel processing. Example:

```
use Parallel::ForkManager;

$pm = new Parallel::ForkManager($MAX_PROCESSES);

foreach $file (@jpeg_files) {
    # Forks and returns the pid for the child:
    my $pid = $pm->start and next; 

    jpegCompress($file);

    $pm->finish; # Terminates the child process
}
```

Comment: Works quite well, except the counter global variables don't work (as each fork is a new process). I might have to look at threads and shared variables.